# Eclipse migration NoClassDefFound GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks

Tags: android, google-play-services

i have a problem with my code.

So far I worked with Eclipse, but now i work with Android Studio.

(In Eclipse)
I have a library project called **MoST**, that requires **google_play_service_r16** library project. To import this project in Android Studio:

1) In Eclipse I add google_play_service_r16 to MoST.

2) Export file as **build.gradle**.

3) Finally i imported build.gradle and then create **MoST.aar** in Android Studio.

In Android Studio i created a new project that uses the MoST module. When i try to run my new application i have this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.unipa.uniar, PID: 23978
                                                                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks;
                                                                         at org.most.MoSTApplication.onCreate(MoSTApplication.java:66)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1032)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5881)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.unipa.uniar-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                         at org.most.MoSTApplication.onCreate(MoSTApplication.java:66) 
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1032) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5881) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

My app module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unipa.uniar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':most')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/weka-3.6.6-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
    compile files('libs/bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
}
```

(Most module) AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.most"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Permission for activity recognition -->

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <application
        android:name="org.most.MoSTApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="MoSTService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The error says ***Most Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks"***

How can i fix the problem?

Comment: Are you sure `play-services-base:` is the correct dependency you need??

Comment: Also, please add the build.gradle of the `most` module

Comment: What kind of device are you running? Which API Level?

Comment: Thanks for help. However I have solved the problem. GooglePlayServicesClient class has been deprecated for some time, so i must to set an old play_service version in modules. This solve the problem.

Comment: @Federico If you have an answer post it as an answer and accept it so the question does not pollute the unanswered feed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

GooglePlayServicesClient class has been deprecated for some time. Recent versions of google play services such as 10.2.1 can create a variety of problems. In my case I can not use newer versions as I can not edit library directly. To solve the problem have included the version of google play service 4.3.23, that include the GooglePlayServiceClient and I solved the problem. AndroidManifest.xml (final):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.unipa.uniar">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Permission for Network -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Permission for activity recognition -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:icon,android:theme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Welcome"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TrainingSet" />
        <activity android:name=".Testing"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unipa.uniar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':most')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/weka-3.6.6-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
    compile files('libs/bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
}
```